# c++ not able to find file (i think)

Tags: c++, eclipse, file, eclipse-cdt

I have the following code (simplified)

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("input.txt");
    if(myFile.is_open())
        cout<<"test";
}
```

However `myFile.is_open()` is returning false;

why?

I'm using eclipse and the input.txt file is right in the src folder with the .cpp file...

Thanks!

Comment: @birryree: it turns out that we've done indipendently the exact same edit. :D

Comment: whoah, sorry! totally forgot to put the code brackets on!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every executable is - by default - **ran from the directory of your project**. So for a tree like this:

```
project
 |- src
 |  |- a.cpp
 |  |- b.cpp
 |  |- foo.txt
 |
 |- Debug
 |  |- a.exe
 |
 |- foo2.txt
```

You shall use the paths like `src/foo.txt` or `foo2.txt`. Your exe is located in `Debug` directory, but it will be ran from your project's directory anyway. In this way, every build configuration's executables are ran in the same way (from the same place).

You can change your working directory and arguments under **Run configurations** (pull-down menu next to the "run" icon). Switch to tab "Arguments", uncheck "use default" and set whichever you'd like if the default's not OK for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check the working directory Eclipse sets for you. It might be that of the binary. Try placing the `input.txt` file in the same directory as that of the binary Eclipse compiles from your code, and then run the application.

To find the working directory setting of your project look in the project's settings dialog.

That said, it's probably a good idea to code in a manner independent from your working directory. You might set the binary's install directory in preprocessor constant string, and have your install script (or configuration script) set that `#define` to the proper directory. Or, if that's not an option, then you might fetch the directory value at runtime.

Comment: Looks like eclipse uses the project directory so I just needed to say src/input.txt Thanks!

Comment: This too should be configurable. I believe there's a Debug directory Eclipse creates somewhere within your project's directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify a full path, the program will search in the current directory, that probably in your case <s>is the directory where the executable is built</s> ***edit:*** *it turns out that by default it's the project directory (thanks @Kos)*.

You can move `input.txt` in that directory, specify a full path (or a correct relative one) or instruct your IDE to start the executable with a different current directory (I don't know if with Eclipse it's possible, I suggest this because with VS you can do that).

By the way, in general you should avoid to hardcode paths in your sources.

Comment: The current directory is the project directory by default.

Answer (score 1):

You have the input.txt in your `source` folder but the application is executed from the `Debug` folder; from the 'source', it's located at `..\Debug`. Just put your text file there and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set up eclipse's working directory to your src directory. I have no idea what the default is.